# Unattended-upgrades hung on reboot

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, reboot, unattended-upgrades

I have a workstation that was recently (yesterday?) upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.5. Today it was lagging, and was rebooted. But before it completed the reboot, it started running unattended-upgrades (I was not there for this so cannot confirm any prompts).

The problem is that six hours later, it still hasn't completed reboot. It displayed the following message for several hours:

```
Unattended-upgrade in progress during shutdown, please don't turn off the computer.
Progress: 94.2857 % (linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic)
```

Most of the existing answers on unattended-upgrades seem to assume access to a working terminal. But Ctrl+Alt+F1-F7 didn't give me a working console (just a black screen with an unresponsive blinking cursor), and I can't access the machine remotely. Is turning it off my only option? If not, how can I force the update to stop? If so, is there a way to know what am I going to break by interrupting the update?

Comment: Sure, your output tells you what's broken: That new kernel. So try rebooting into an older kernel at GRUB, then reinstall that kernel package.

Comment: @user535733 thanks! I tried to use GRUB as you suggested, but the machine ignored my Shift and started up normally. Will try reinstalling the new kernel later on.

Comment: Use ESC instead of Shift.